# symfony 2 form : I would like to use custom field name attribute or manipulate child in form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I'm trying to use Symfony 2 forms to easily use Doctrine findBy API in my Controllers.

Actually, I would like to write this code in my Controller:

```
$repository->findBy(
    $request->get('filters'),
    $request->get('orderBy'),
    $request->get('limit'),
    $request->get('offset')
);
```

For that, my URL should look like this!

- /session?filters[user]=4
- /session?filters[user]=4&filters[year]=2014&orderBy=date&limit=10

To be able to give this functionality to my user, a solution I would love to use forms :

**Solution n°1**

```
$this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('filters', 'array')
            ->add('user', 'integer')
            ->add('year', 'integer')
        ->add('orderBy')
        ->add('limit')
        ->add('offset')
        ;
```

But this solution or equivalent does not exist. (the type array does not exist)

**Solution n°2**

```
$this->createFormBuilder()
        ->add('filters[user]', 'integer')
        ->add('filters[year]', 'integer')
        ->add('orderBy')
        ->add('limit')
        ->add('offset')
        ;
```

The usage of '[' and ']' chars are not allowed and produce error.

An other solution is to use custom field name, actually the first solution (without the unexistant type "array")  will produce this HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="form_filters" name="form[filters]" required="required" class="form-control">
```

Which will not suits the URL requirements. Do someone knows how to use custom name attribute?
It would also work If I had the opportunity to change the attribute name to **form[filters][something]** or even better **filters[something]** .

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure as I never did that, but, why don't you try with [`collection`](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/collection.html) type ?

```
$this->createFormBuilder()
    ->add('filters', 'collection', array(
        'choices' => array(
            'user',
            'year',
        )
    ))
    [...]
```

However I'm not sure you want pass parameters via get: if you have a form and url isn't callable from "outside" of your application, POST is far better